# How to prevent Cassini from auto-launching when a debug session starts in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a solution with multiple possible start-up projects. One of them is a web application. When I start to debug, Cassini automatically launches even if I do not want to debug the web application. This is quite annoying.

Do anyone of you know how to disable Cassini auto-start "feature"

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the web project properties window (CTRL+W,P) and set 'Always Start When Debugging' to 'False'.

[image: Properties Window]

Answer (score 3):

I didn't like the modify solution/project approach, so I figured out a local "hack".
I don't like modifying the project files for two reasons:

1. Some prefer Cassini over IIS or want certain projects to be hosted.
2. The default project setting uses Cassini and we all forget to change the project properties.

Create a dummy .exe for Visual studio to launch instead of the real deal:

1. Create a c# empty console application project with no other code in Main().
2. Change the project properties to "Windows Application" output type to suppress the console window.
3. Build the .exe
4. Copy .exe to ~\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0, and rename it to "WebDev.WebServer40.exe" (for .NET 2.0 create a copy of the dummy .exe as WebDev.WebServer20.exe).

Debug your codes and enjoy the performance! This was also a bonus fix to the random visual studio unit test debugging timeout exception.